# How can I use Perl's XML::LibXML to extract content between tags?

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I have an XML file with content like this:

```
<Node id="7"/>
www
<Node id="10"/>
```

How is it possible using XML::LibXML and Perl to take the content between the two nodes, ie "www"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML format that you have deal with is *awful*!*

Given a node, you want the nodes that are its siblings, immediately follow it (except perhaps for intermediary comments) and are text nodes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( XML_COMMENT_NODE XML_TEXT_NODE );

sub following_text {
   my ($node) = @_;
   my $text = '';
   while ($node = $node->nextSibling()) {
      my $node_type = $node->nodeType();
      next if $node_type == XML_COMMENT_NODE;
      last if $node_type != XML_TEXT_NODE;
      $text .= $node->data();   
   }

   return $text;
}

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_fh(\*DATA);
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();
my ($node) = $root->findnodes('//Node[@id="7"]');
my $text   = following_text($node);

say $text;
```

```
__DATA__
<root>
<Node id="7"/>
www
<Node id="10"/>
bar
</root>
```

* — `www` should be a child of `Node`. For example, `<Node id="7">www</Node>` would be better.

Comment: Thans a lot for your reply. It was very helpful. The key to the solution was "nextSibling()" method. And for the XML format, yes, it's awful, but i can't change it to another format. So, i have to deal with this. But it's ok, i can extract what i want from my xml file now.

Comment: @user1437832, If the answer meets your needs, please approve it (click the checkmark) to mark your problem resolved.